# Mysterious 15 points appear and disappear with no trail

Tags: support, reputation

This is an issue I've experienced several times but it's just today I was able to see the whole  "process". I've tried to look at this site for any related issues but I was unable, so if this is a duplicate I'll just raise my shield.

Sometimes, I notice an increment update of my points by 15 (like if someone had accepted my answer on some question). Normally, after 2-3 seconds, the `Recent achievements` icon changes its shape and shows how much points have been added to my reputation with a green background, but when this issue happens, it just doesn't appear: I just see the points added.

So at this point, I have some new 15 points in my reputation and as I don't see where they come from, I try opening my profile and see my last reputation movements: absolutely nothing, and the 15 points that were added get dropped. So basically I have the same reputation before I noticed those points were added. If I don't update the page I still keep the new reputation (until I reload).

As there's no harm, it's curiosity what I feel: Why does this happen? Is it some kind of bug?

Comment: someone accept and then unaccepted your answer.

Comment: Many times, a new user doesn't realize that they can accept only one answer, and they attempt to accept many answers.  When they accept your answer, then accept someone else's answer, yours gets automatically unaccepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone most likely accepted an answer by you then unaccepted it, almost immediately.

You got notified about the accept, but since negative reputation changes are not notified, you didn't get notified about that.

Comment: Ok, but wouldn't I see something in the reputation tab of my profile? I usually see when someone "unaccepts" some previously "accepted" question, why I don't see this?

Comment: @NKN - not if they were done very closely together. If you got no other reputation on such a day, the history would show a record with "no reputation changes" (as opposed to no record at all).